# brctl Not working fine with bridging eth0 and at0

Tags: linux, bridge

I made an access point with airbase-ng and its at0

I tried to bridge my eth0 and at0 by

```
brctl addbr demo
brctl addif demo eth0
brctl addif demo at0
brctl demo up
dhclient3 demo &
already removed eth0 ip
```

so when i use

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -I eth0
```

theres no reply but if i use

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -I demo
```

it works!!!

In browser internet works fine so when i connect my android with at0 (access point) it should same work. but its now working at all :(

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was with the emulator I was using.
I was using virtualbox and facing this issue, but when I tried with VMware it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: There's a long standing issue with VirtualBox and having multiple ether addresses on WiFi interfaces.